# Standard way for reverse pointer iterators

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, reverse

Is there something like `rbegin` and `rend` for pointers?

I have pointers to the head and tail of a c-style string but would like to create reverse iterators for them.

I want to know if there is a way to do this that is supplied by the standard, or if I have to write my own code for this.

EDIT: I am using low level code for a reason. No `std::basic_string` and such. Goal is to use `std::find` to find last occurrence of a value.

Comment: `std::reverse_iterator<char*>`

Comment: Put the C-style string into a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: What do you want out of the iterators.  In general I think of iterators as abstractions of pointers.  If you want to use std algorithms they already work as long as end is one past the last element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `std::reverse_iterator`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    const char* s = "abc";
    std::reverse_iterator<const char*> first(s + 3);
    std::reverse_iterator<const char*> last(s);
    for( ; first != last; ++first) {
        std::cout << *first;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new C++ 2014 Standard includes corresponding functions for arrays

```
template <class T, size_t N> reverse_iterator<T*> rbegin(T (&array)[N]);
template <class T, size_t N> reverse_iterator<T*> rend(T (&array)[N]);
```

In fact they use simply std::reverse_iterator.

So if your compiler does not support these functions you can write yourself

```
std::reverse_iterator<char *> first( tail );
std::reverse_iterator<char *> last( head );
```